# "Unable to map all paths to URIs" error on Page publishing

Tags: publishing, content-manager, publishingfailed

Below is the stack trace for it :

```
Unable to map all paths to URIs.
```

StackTrace Information Details:

```
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetTcmUri(String uri)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetObject(String uri)
   at xyz.ContentManagement.Tridion.Resolvers.ProductResolver.ProcessPage(IdentifiableObject item, PublishContext context, ISet`1 resolvedItems)
   at xyz.ContentManagement.Tridion.Resolvers.ProductResolver.Resolve(IdentifiableObject item, ResolveInstruction instruction, PublishContext context, ISet`1 resolvedItems)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.ResolveItems(IEnumerable`1 items, ResolveInstruction instruction, IEnumerable`1 contexts)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.ResolveItem(IdentifiableObject item, ResolveInstruction instruction, PublishContext context)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.HandlePublishRequest(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.ProcessPublishTransaction(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.QueueMessageHandler.HandleMessage()
```

The Page published successfully on removal of this Component Presentation.
Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the provided Stack Trace, the problem seems to be in a custom resolver: `xxx.ContentManagement.Tridion.Resolvers.ProductResolver`.

This resolver calls `Session.GetObject(string)` and given the error message, it seem that the string is a non-existing WebDAV URL.

You should debug the custom resolver to figure out what is going on exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Rick. The issue has been resolved, it was due to the change in folder location of the concerned ComponentTemplate and the dynamic component template "Product Resolver" referring to the Webdev Path of the old folder location.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please note that this should be a comment on my answer (which should be accepted).